# Incorrect syntax near ',' in SQL dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

When I compile there are no issues, but when I execute this stored procedure, I get:

> Incorrect syntax near ','

I can't for the life of me figure out where the issue is:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT idea, id, posted_by
  FROM
  (idea,id, posted_by, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @sortExpression + ') as RowNum
   FROM ideas e
     INNER JOIN buckets d ON
        e.bucket_id = d.id
   WHERE e.bucket_id = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @bucketId) + '
  ) as EmpInfo
  WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + 
           ' AND (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + ' + ' 
           + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @maximumRows) + ') - 1'

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Can you output the `@sql` variable and post the result here. The prepared statement is correct but the concatenated string may not be. Meaning that the `EXEC` function is causing the error.

Comment: That subquery looks like it is missing its `SELECT`.

Comment: Try `SELECT @sql` before the `EXEC`

Comment: using "print(@sql)", you can able to see your query.

Comment: missing an inner query SELECT

Comment: If you're using [sp_ExecuteSql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx), why aren't you using parameters? What's the  need for this proc then, why not Exec? And second, please always use PRINT @sql before executing. This will help debugging.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be concatenating all of those things into dynamic SQL. In fact you should try to get the ORDER BY expression working without introducing dynamic SQL at all, but I understand that this can be problematic when users can pick several columns, different data types, and both directions ([I discussed this problem here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/conditional-order-by). So please pass in the other parameters safely:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000); -- always use semi-colons

DECLARE @r INT;

SET @r = @startRowIndex + @maximumRows - 1;

SET @sql = 'SELECT idea, id, posted_by
FROM
(
   SELECT -- this was your actual problem 
     idea,id, posted_by, -- you should prefix these with the alias
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @sortExpression + ') as RowNum
   FROM dbo.ideas e -- always use schema prefix
   INNER JOIN dbo.buckets d ON
    e.bucket_id = d.id
   WHERE e.bucket_id = @bucketId
) as EmpInfo
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND @r;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@startRowIndex INT, @bucketId INT, @r INT', 
  @startRowIndex, @bucketId, @r;
```

For some of my comments:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)
- [Ladies and gentlemen, start your semi-colons!](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)
- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Also, if you're using SQL Server 2012, you should probably be using [`OFFSET` / `FETCH`](https://sqlblog.org/2010/11/10/sql-server-v-next-denali-using-the-offset-clause-paging).

Answer (score 1):

You need a SELECT at the beginning of your inner query

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT idea, id, posted_by
  FROM
(**SELECT** idea,id, posted_by, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @sortExpression + ') as  RowNum
FROM ideas e
 INNER JOIN buckets d ON
    e.bucket_id = d.id
WHERE e.bucket_id = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @bucketId) + '
) as EmpInfo
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + 
       ' AND (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + ' + ' 
       + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @maximumRows) + ') - 1'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Hopefully that shows up correctly.  I was trying to bold the work SELECT

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an inner `select`

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT idea, id, posted_by
  FROM
  (**SELECT** idea,id, posted_by, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @sortExpression + ') as RowNum
   FROM ideas e
     INNER JOIN buckets d ON
        e.bucket_id = d.id
   WHERE e.bucket_id = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @bucketId) + '
  ) as EmpInfo
  WHERE RowNum BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + 
           ' AND (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + ' + ' 
           + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @maximumRows) + ') - 1'

 EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```